# List as headerText of p:columns

Tags: jsf, arraylist, primefaces, datatable, header

I'm trying to get my `List<String>` content as `headerText` of my `<p:columns>`.

I've tried this without any luck:

```
<p:dataTable id="lineData" value="#{loadFile.firstLine}" var="p">
    <p:columns headerText="#{loadFile.firstLine}" var="column">  
        ...                
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

My `firstLine` list is a `ArrayList<String>`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The attribute `headerText` expects `String` value, not `ArrayList<String>`. Maybe you should make it as `#{loadFile.firstLine[0]}`.

Comment: why do you even want that to happen? please add more details on your question like what happens when you try putting a list in the headerText attribute, etc